# ELIPS Studio 3 - Validating email address

Tags: validation, elips-studio

How can I check the given email id is valid or not using ELIPS Studio 3?  Is it possible?

Thanks in  Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to validate an email ID formay then you can use [regular expression](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=12_Using_Regular_Expressions_03.html). if you are looking at validating a email address to see if it exists or not then there is no way.